# Should I carry on porting FPDF to .NET?

Tags: php, .net, porting, fpdf

I've started to port FPDF to .NET, however I was wondering if its worth the effort.

**Has it already been done?**

I'm aware of ASP FPDF, but I'm talking about creating a native .NET dll so that any .NET language can use it. I plan to make it public for any one to use.

Further I'm not familiar with PHP, what **tips/advice** can you give (in terms of porting)?

Comment: Does it have any advantage over existing PDF libraries for .NET like iTextSharp?

Comment: I've tried iTextSharp, FPDF seems much easier to produce what you want. I have created PDF by hand in notepad, this worked but was too much effort. I then tried creating my own PDF lib, but decided not to re-invent the wheel. Looking at the different libs i've been drawn to FPDF.

So to answer you question, ease of use and familiarity for those who have used FPDF.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to port a recent PDF library which is still actively being developed (ie. [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org))? It already supports UTF-8 and a lot of other things that don't work with FPDF...

Comment: I have never heard of TCPDF, what language is this in?

Comment: TCPDF is also written in PHP.  I believe it started as a fork of FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

[pdfforge](http://www.pdfforge.org/) (the makers of PDFCreator) wrote [fly2pdf](http://www.pdfforge.org/other-projects), which is a free (for non-commercial use) ActiveX library for creating PDF files.